# How to Debug Analytics in React Native Firebase using Expo?

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, expo, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

I'm working on an app in **React Native** and I use **Expo** to run it on iOS and Android simulators.
I've connected **React Native Firebase** to **React Navigation** and I use `logScreenView` to log data to GA.

How can I turn on the Debug Mode in RNFirebase to confirm if everything works and logs as expected?

Right now I do receive **some** data when switching the screens and watching the Realtime GA View, but of course, it is not 100% real-time, and it's impossible to fully debug that way. I am not sure if all works as it should.
I had GA Realtime view on one monitor while working on the code and clicking through the app over a couple hours. Sometimes, let's say every 20-30 minutes **something** was visible in the Realtime report. And at that moment it seemed to make sense, the screen titles were logging correctly. I had screens with titles "ProductPage - Product 1" and "ProductPage - Product 2" both were logged.
I set Analytics 3 days ago and right now, in my reports, I don't see all the page titles that I have seen in previous days while working on it in the real-time view. For example I don't see "ProductPage - Product 1" but see "ProductPage - Product 2" but with much lower views number than expected (I opened it like 20 times and now I see only 5).
I don't know if something is wrong of it needs more time to calculate the data?

So it seems to be somehow ok, but the data is strange and I'm not sure. There is a section about [Seeing Events in Firebase Consoles Debug View](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage#seeing-events-in-firebase-consoles-debugview) but as I am using Expo for my app, I don't know how to do it. I would highly appreciate some help with this!
I would like to turn the Debug Mode on iOS and/or Android - doesn't matter.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After some time I managed to make the Debug Mode work on Android simulator. Below are my steps, I hope it might help someone.
If anyone know how to turn the Debug Mode on iOS simulator - please answer.

**For Android**

1/
I had to install ADB (https://developer.android.com/tools/adb) that is included in the Android SDK Platform Tools package.
I did it through Android Studio in SDK Manager (Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools and checked Android SDK Platforms-Tools

2/ It is installed here `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools` so I had to `cd` there and run `./adb shell`. Then according to doccumentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#android I can enable the debug mode using `setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app PACKAGE_NAME`. Package Name is set in my `app.json` in `expo.android.package`

3/ to verify if it is set you can run `getprop debug.firebase.analytics.app` and you should get your package name

3/ At the end I needed to wipe the data from my Android simulator and reinstall the app (development build).

Events started to be visible in DebugView with ~30-60s delay.